# Deserializing a nested .json object in c#

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization, json.net

I am trying to deserialize a nested .json (https://ergast.com/api/f1/current/results.json) in C# from an API, but I'm kind of stuck. I have looked everywhere for a solution to my problem and haven't found anything helpful yet, I probably just don't grasp how it could help me, considering I am new to c# and APIs in general, and not exactly the most experienced of programmers.

I am calling the following method in an aspx Page_Load where I download the raw .json, format it slightly and deserialize it into *racesCollection.*

```
private static RacesCollection GetRacesFromAPI(WebClient webClient)
        {
            String JSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json?callback=myParser&limit=1000");
            JObject data = FormatJSON(ref JSON);
            RacesCollection racesCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RacesCollection>(data["MRData"]["RaceTable"].ToString());
            return racesCollection;
        }
```

..This is the collection of races

```
    public class RacesCollection
    {
        private List<Races> races;
        public List<Races> Races { get => races; set => races = value; }
    }
```

..and these are the classes i'm trying to deserialize to.

```
    public class Races
    {
        int season;
        string round;
        string url;
        string raceName;
        string date;
        string time;

        public int Season { get => season; set => season = value; }
        public string Round { get => round; set => round = value; }
        public string Url { get => url; set => url = value; }
        public string RaceName { get => raceName; set => raceName = value; }
        public string Date { get => date; set => date = value; }
        public string Time { get => time; set => time = value; }

        public Dictionary<string, Circuit> Circuit { get; set; }
        public List<Results> Results { get; set; }
    }
    public class Circuit
    {
        string circuitID;
        string circuitUrl;
        string circuitName;

        public string CircuitID { get => circuitID; set => circuitID = value; }
        public string CircuitUrl { get => circuitUrl; set => circuitUrl = value; }
        public string CircuitName { get => circuitName; set => circuitName = value; }
        public Dictionary<string, Location> Location { get; set; }
    }
    public class Results
    {
        int number;
        int position;
        int points;
        int grid;
        int laps;
        string status;
        public int Number { get => number; set => number = value; }
        public int Position { get => position; set => position = value; }
        public int Points { get => points; set => points = value; }
        public int Grid { get => grid; set => grid = value; }
        public int Laps { get => laps; set => laps = value; }
        public string Status { get => status; set => status = value; }
        public Dictionary<string, Driver> Driver { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, Constructor> Constructor { get; set; }
    }
    public class Driver
    {
        string driverId;
        public string DriverId { get => driverId; set => driverId = value; }
    }
    public class Constructor
    {
        string constructorId;
        public string ConstructorId { get => constructorId; set => constructorId = value; }
    }


    public class Location
    {
        float lat;
        float @long;
        string locality;
        string country;

        public float Lat { get => lat; set => lat = value; }
        public float Long { get => @long; set => @long = value; }
        public string Locality { get => locality; set => locality = value; }
        public string Country { get => country; set => country = value; }
    }
```

When running, everything deserializes fine until it reaches Circuit, which throws this exception.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value "albert_park" to type 'JSONAPI.Circuit'. Path 'Races[0].Circuit.circuitId', line 10, position 34.'
>
> Inner exception
> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to JSONAPI.Circuit.

Any help I could get on this would be very appreciated.

Comment: JSON keys are suppose to be case sensitive. You have `CircuitID` in your C# object and the JSON is `circuitId`.  Update your C# object and see how that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It still throws the same exception unfortunately.

Comment: Change `public Dictionary<string, Circuit> Circuit { get; set; }` to `public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }`  Circuit is a JSON object, not a dictionary.  Same with `Location` on circuit.

Comment: Thank you, Sean! This worked. Though I've stumbled upon yet another problem, i'm still stuck on trying to make Results work, since it's an array. It doesn't return an exception by using `public Results Results{ get; set; }` but it's just null. I've tried using 
        `public List<Results> Results { get; set; }` as well as `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Results> Results{ get; set; }` but none of them work and Results is always null.

Comment: I posted my comment into an answer, also I am not seeing any Result data inside the JSON, so it will naturally be null.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The "Results" data can be found on the bottom of every "Races" entry. I'm not sure how to access it, and what i've tried thus far is in the comment above. See attached screenshot for reference, it's on the very bottom: https://gyazo.com/7af7eb364cb8ec6dfa2d5172cd5bee31

Comment: I can't see the actual json object for the result with that image. Can paste 1 of the result objects in comment or on your original question?

Comment: My bad, I managed to paste the wrong link in the OP. It should be correct now, this is the full .json: https://ergast.com/api/f1/current/results.json
Alternatively a screencap of "Results":
https://gyazo.com/d741f965cb8f57939c5f15713e9f1acb

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out! In all my frustration over this i've failed to see that the same link I pasted before is the same one i've tried using. In any case, thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON libraries will automatically convert the Key-Value pairs to class references for you. 
Just change `public Dictionary<string, Circuit> Circuit { get; set; }` to `public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }`.

This applies to `Location`, `Driver`, and `Constructor` dictionaries in your C# objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the json that you mentioned, circuit is an object in races collection as opposed to dictionary.
[image]
So, please modify Circuit property on your Races class:

```
public class Races
{
    int season;
    string round;
    string url;
    string raceName;
    string date;
    string time;

    public int Season { get => season; set => season = value; }
    public string Round { get => round; set => round = value; }
    public string Url { get => url; set => url = value; }
    public string RaceName { get => raceName; set => raceName = value; }
    public string Date { get => date; set => date = value; }
    public string Time { get => time; set => time = value; }

    public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }
    public List<Results> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in the json that posted, Location property's lat and long are strings as opposed to decimals. So, you might need to modify the data types of lat and long as well.

Side but related note, instead of having private properties with lower case, remove private properties and rename public properties to match your json response. If you don't want to rename properties to camel case then either you can decorate each property with JsonProperty (as shown below for the property Season, but same applies for other properties to match json)

```
public class Races
{
/*  
    int season;
    string round;
    string url;
    string raceName;
    string date;
    string time;
*/
    [JsonProperty("season")]
    public int Season { get; set; }
    /*
    // or use camelcasing like below then no need use JsonProperty attribute
    public int season { get; set; }
    */
    public string Round { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string RaceName { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }

    public Circuit Circuit { get; set; }
    public List<Results> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
RacesCollection racesCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RacesCollection>(data["MRData"]["RaceTable"].ToString(), settings);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I'll try to make another variant using this method.